# How can I replace a table with a new one using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Whats the best way to replace a `<table>` with a new one using jQuery? I'm using ajax on the page to get the new data.

Comment: This is a very broad question. The answer will depend on how is your server script sending the data. Is it using JSON, XML, partial HTML or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to add a wrapper element, something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yoururl.php',
    success: function(r) {
        $('table#something').replaceWith(r);
    }
});
```

..assuming the response you get is an table element.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a div, and:

```
$("#myDiv").load("/some/url.php"); // where url.php outputs the entire table
```

You can specify a portion of the remote document to insert by putting it's selector with the URL parameter as follows:

```
$("#myDiv").load("/some/url.php #myTable");
```